# Only the parent class using django-models-utils

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm using `django-models-utils` in order to obtain all the children of a class. I've succeeded in that but now I don't seem to be able to obtain a view with just the parent class now.

This is the main class, the other classes are for reviews:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    notable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

    objects = InheritanceManager()
```

This is the view for all posts (including the children), which is working:

```
def all_posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('published').filter(published__lte=timezone.now()).select_subclasses()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

This is the view for just the posts (which are not reviews, not children), but this isn't working as I'm getting all posts:

```
class RamblingList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'ramblings'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(published__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published')
    template_name = 'blog/rambling_list.html'
```

Can anyone tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `InheritanceManager` is not supposed to do that. If you call any filter without calling `select_subclasses()`, it will return all objects without the subclass cast.

It is clear in the documentation: http://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager

> But when you iterate over nearby_places, you’ll get only Place instances back, even for objects that are “really” Restaurant or Bar

You could do something like this to achieve the desired effect:

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(
    published__lte=timezone.now()
).order_by('published').select_subclasses()
queryset = [x for x in queryset if type(x) == Post]
```

Comment: I still get the same problem. Strangely enough, on the admin interface, whenever I create an element of one of the subclasses, it shows on the Post interface too. What do you think might be wrong?

Comment: Maybe you could create a class `GeneralPost` that extends `Post`, so that its separated in the admin site?